# How do I run QEMU with a 64-bit processor on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, iso, qemu

I'm running [Ubuntu 11.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29) (Natty Narwhal) 64-bit and recently installed qemu-kvm. Now I want to start a 64-bit [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) using:

```
qemu -m 512 -boot d -cdrom archlinux-2010.05-netinstall-x86_64.iso
```

This loads the image, and I can select to boot [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) the normal way, but it will give me an error that I have to use a 64-bit machine to run this live CD. Now, I tried to get a list of CPUs QEMU can emulate for me, and ended up with this output:

```
axle@z370l:~/Downloads$ qemu -cpu ?
x86           [n270]
x86         [athlon]
x86       [pentium3]
x86       [pentium2]
x86        [pentium]
x86            [486]
x86        [coreduo]
x86          [kvm32]
x86         [qemu32]
x86          [kvm64]
x86       [core2duo]
x86         [phenom]
x86         [qemu64]
x86           [host]
```

So, how do I make QEMU emulate a 64-bit CPU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked myself the same question a few days ago and couldn't figure it out. Now I see your list (perhaps I couldn't find how to get this list?) and the obvious choices seem to be `kvm64`, `qemu64` and `host`. I also tried `core2duo` and `phenom`, they also work.

Comment: Oh... dang it, I got confused by the x86 in front of all these entries... But now it get's a little clearer, since 64bit still is x86_64 ;). This solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

> I asked myself the same question a few days ago and couldn't figure it out. Now I see your >list (perhaps I couldn't find how to get this list?) and the obvious choices seem to be >kvm64, qemu64 and host. I also tried core2duo and phenom, they also work.

Running "qemu -cpu qemu64 ..." (or other architectures) did not work for me (on Debian Sid/unstable).  I did get my 64bit ISO image to run with "qemu-system-x86_64 ..."

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm that -cpu qemu64 (or the other) did not work for me on Debian Wheezy but qemu-system-x86_64 works.

Answer (score 2):

This command worked well for me, maybe it can help someone else:

```
qemu /path/to/hdfile -m 900 -vga std -enable-kvm -cdrom ~/file.iso -boot d -net user -usb -cpu kvm64
```