# Running 64 bit Ubuntu distribution from 32 bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, qemu, emulation, architecture

Related to this question [How do I run QEMU with a 64-bit processor on a 64-bit machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40046/how-do-i-run-qemu-with-64bit-processor-on-a-64bit-machine). I'm trying to run Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit under Ubuntu 11.04 32 bit using qemu on a core2duo (64 bit CPU) machine, using the following qemu parameters with no success.

Error under qemu:

> This kernel required an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
>   Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropiate for your CPU

Isn't qemu supposed to emulate a 64 bit machine?

I think I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out.

```
qemu -cpu (kvm64|core2duo|qemu64) -boot d -cdrom ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso
qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

`uname -m` returns

```
i686
```

`/proc/cpuinfo` returns

```
processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8400  @ 2.26GHz
stepping    : 6
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 lahf_lm dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority
bogomips    : 4522.45
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, VirtualBox can do this, but not `qemu`. Also, you need to have support for this kind of virtual machine enabled by the BIOS, and not all systems come with the option.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

- `qemu-system-x86_64`

Instead of:

- `qemu`